# print all words before a specific character

Tags: php

Im having a problem with my function.

1. The user is able to post text to the page and set categories to the article.
   categories that is set is saved in mysql in this way: categorie1,categorie2,categorie3

So, I want my visitors to be able to choose categories by providing a list with all categories.

This is how im thinking:

```
  <?php
  $sql02 = "SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY id";
  $result02 = mysql_query($sql02); 


  while($rad02 = mysql_fetch_array($result02))
  {
  ?>

  <?php

      $before = "<li><a href='index.php?p=cmd&kat=TEST'>";
      $string =  $rad02["kategori"];
      $newstring = str_ireplace(",", "<br>", $string);
      $kat = $newstring;

  ?>
      <li><a href='index.php?p=cmd&kat=<?php echo $kat; ?>'><php echo "$kat"; ?></a></li>

  <?php
      }
  ?>
```

But that does not work.. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why all the starting and stopping of PHP. If you see `?> <?php` then there is no point or need for either

Comment: In what way ___does it not work___

Comment: Check the basics of HTML a `<li>` requires a `</li>` an `<a>` requires and `</a>` You do it correctly sometimes but not all the time.

Comment: I have resolved this now, But got a new problem. Please se my new post

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `$kat = $newstring;` and when you said `echo "$kat";` you shouldn't put **$kat** into ""

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi! I it did help but I have a new problem now. Its making a <br> after every "," but when i put it in a link i get category1<br>category2. Can anyone help me to only put category1 in a link etc.

Comment: Are all categories in one row or category1 has id1, category2 has id2 etc.

Comment: All are in one row

Answer (score 0):

If every categorie has it's own **id** you can do this than with foreach loop like this

```
while($rad02 = mysqli_fetch_array($result02)){
$rads[] = $rad02;
}
foreach($rads = $rad02){
?>
<li><a href='index.php?p=cmd&kat=<?php echo $rad02['kategori']; ?>'><?php echo $rad02['karegori']; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```